HTML Dialog element and tab behavior
Before the introduction of the <dialog> element, the recommended usage of the dialog role was to trap the tab order within the dialog element, i.e. if the user tabs to the last element within the dialog, it should wrap back to the first element.
The native dialog element, at least how it's implemented on Firefox and Chrome, does not do this, but rather lets the user tab around to the address bar etc, and then tabs back into the dialog element.
Is this tab behavior no longer necessary or recommended with the native dialog element? I wasn't able to find any advice about how to handle tab order when using the element. w3c just says the following:

Authors SHOULD focus an element in the modal dialog when it is displayed, and authors SHOULD manage focus of modal dialogs.

But doesn't go into detail as to what "manage" means

Here is an example from w3c using role="dialog": https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialog-modal/examples/dialog/
And here is an example of the native dialog element: https://codepen.io/jajenkinson/full/JjqEYox


I think they just refer broadly to this concept -- any given website will have different needs and design decisions to be made, so "do it this specific way always" would be poor advice. Instead the guidelines suggest following the principle of least surprise, more or less.

Pretty interesting, I also just noticed that ARIA recommends authors to manage focus within a modal dialog! That would even mean using arrow keys inside to set focus. Seems at odds with a focus trap.

I think that behavior of Chrome and Firefox is correct. It's same with simple web page without dialogs, once you reach last focusable element focus restarts at the browser level (tabs, address bar etc.).
With dialog it's the same except it ignores focusable elements outside the active dialog.
